# Join two functions to one

Tags: functions, function-construction

If I have, for example

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{u'[t] == u[t], u[0] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 1}]
sol2 = NDSolve[{u'[t] == u[t], u[0] == 1}, u, {t, 1, 2}]
sol = Join[sol1, sol2]
```

I expected to get one function that goes from 0 to 2, but intead I get a list of two functions.
How can I join sol1 and sol2 in order to get one function on a larger interval?

Comment: Your example is continuous at $t=1$, so why should joining them produce a discontinuity? Also, which given solution did you use?

Comment: I already wrote this today: Just because you wish something works like you want it to, doesn't make it true. Have you ever considered reading the definition of `Join`?

Answer (score 1):

How bout this

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{u'[t] == u[t], u[0] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 1}]
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{u'[t] == u[t], u[0] == 1}, u, {t, 1, 2}]

sol[t_?NumericQ] :=  Piecewise[{{sol1[t], 0 <= t <= 1}, {sol2[t], 1 < t <= 2}}];

Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]